# Action Bar Button won't respond to Touch events

Tags: android, events, android-actionbar, touch

I would like to have a `Button` in my `ActionBar` that does something when you touch it, and something else when you release it.

```
private Button mButton;

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mButton = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_button, null);

    mButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "This line never executes...");
            return false;
        }
    }

    menu.getItem(0).setActionView(mButton);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

As written above, nothing in onTouch ever happens when I touch the Button. I have another button in the same menu (I get it with `getItem(1)`) set up the way a button normally works - with an `onClickListener` - and it works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionMenuPrestener` is an internal class that controls the menus that appear in the `ActionBar`. If a `MenuItem` has  submenu, it will attach a `View.OnTouchListener` that allows the user to drag their finger forward to open the submenu. If the `MenuItem` doesn't have a submenu, is sets the `View.OnTouchListener` to `null`.

In other words, you can't attach a `View.OnTouchListener` to a `MenuItem` because the framework will remove it. You best bet is to create a custom `View` for your `ActionBar`, then attach a `View.OnTouchListener` to that.

[If you'd like to view the source for the `ActionMenuPrestener`, you can do so here.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuPresenter.java#L167)

Comment: I apologize for missing this answer. I ended up going a different route with the UI for this feature, but your answer does explain why this wasn't working and what I would've had to do to make it work, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do it:

```
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuItem yourItem = menu.add("Your_item");
                yourItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                View yourItemView = new ImageView(this);
                yourItemView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_icon_drawable));
                yourItem.setActionView(yourItemView);
                yourItemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
                                // do your touch stuff here
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP");
                                // do your release stuff here
                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
```